# how to insert multiselect values into database in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

**View Code:**

```
      <div class="col-sm-10">
              <select multiple="multiple" class="form-control"    
      name="serial-lists[]" id="serial-lists[]" required>
                <option value="1.0.0.1">1.0.0.1</option>
                <option value="1.0.0.2">1.0.0.2</option>
                <option value="1.0.0.3">1.0.0.3</option>
                <option value="1.0.0.4">1.0.0.3</option>
                <option value="1.0.0.5">1.0.0.3</option>
                <option value="1.0.0.6">1.0.0.4</option>
                <option value="1.0.0.7">1.0.0.5</option>
              </select>
            </div>
```

This is my view code. Here I am selecting multiple values and need to insert into database.

**Controller code:**

```
     $versions = new supportedversionsModel;
     $versions->supportedversions = implode(',', $request-
     >input('serial-lists'));
     $versions->build()->associate($temp);
     $versions->save();
```

This is my controller code.Here it should save the selected values into db.BUt on insertion it throws error .ie.,**Array to string conversion on insertion**

**SupportedversionsModel CODE:**

```
class supportedversionsModel extends Model
{

 protected $table="HaghwaySupports";
 protected $connections="mysql";

  public function build(){

        return $this->belongsToMany(debModel::class);
    }
}
```

**Migration code for supportedversion table:**

```
class HaghwaySupversiosn extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('HaghwaySupports', function($table) {
            $table->engine='InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('build_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('supportedversions');
            $table->foreign('build_id')->references('buildid')-
            >on('MainHaghway');
            $table->timestamps();

        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('HaghwaySupports');
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `dd($versions);` to check if it is a legal model object

Comment: where should I need to mention it

Comment: try to do dd($versions); before the $versions->save;

Comment: yes sir,dd($versions)works

Comment: It shows                                          supportedversionsModel {#228 ▼
  #table: "HaghwaySupports"
  #connections: "mysql"
  #connection: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:2 [▶]
  #original: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #events: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: array:1 [▶]
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}

Comment: Then click triangle after `#attributes` to check it.

Answer (score 0):

Save it as JSON String.

```
 $versions = new supportedversionsModel;
 $versions->supportedversions =  json_encode(implode(',', $request->input('serial-lists')));     
 $versions->build()->associate($temp);
 $versions->save();
```

And when retrieving,

```
$versions->serial_list = json_decode($serial_list, true);
```

Gothrough this for more info:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-serialization

Comment: [{"salesPackage":"[\"acces\",\"manusa\"]"},{"salesPackage":"[\"acces\",\"manusa\"]"},{"salesPackage":"[\"aa\",\"bb\"]"},{"salesPackage":"[\"accessories\",\"manual\"]"},{"salesPackage":"[\"jj\",\"kk\"]"}]-->this is my encoded json value

Comment: $salesPackage->salesPackage=json_encode($formdescription->input('package'));-->this is how I encode it